# Removing child override by another code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a button that automatically adds a child and takes away health once clicked. I also made the button take away 0 if the child = true. However, I have another button that once clicked, it should move to another frame and remove the child. For some reason, it isn't removing the child. Before, I didn't have the button take away 0 if the child = true and the removeChild worked fine. The code is all in a frame named actions on the main timeline.

```
var createGirlText = new GirlSpeechBoxClass();

 if(EnergyNumber <= 0) {
        Girl_btn.buttonMode = false;
        Girl_btn.mouseEnabled = false;
    }

Girl_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GirlTalk); 
Girl_btn.buttonMode = true;

function GirlTalk(event:MouseEvent){
    addChild(createGirlText);
    createGirlText.x = 350.95;
    createGirlText.y = 488.95;
   EnergyNumber -= 10;
   if(createGirlText = true){
       EnergyNumber -= 0;
   }
   if(EnergyNumber < 0) {
    EnergyNumber = 0;
    }
     if(EnergyNumber <= 0) {
        Girl_btn.buttonMode = false;
        Girl_btn.mouseEnabled = false;
    }
}

//Action for clicking Main Button
BacktoOutside_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMainArea2); 
BacktoOutside_btn.buttonMode = true;

function gotoMainArea2(event:MouseEvent){
   gotoAndStop("MainArea");
   MovieClip(this.root).removeChild(createGirlText);
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, just a comment on your naming conventions. It's common practice to use camel case for naming objects. So in your case I would rename `EnergyNumber`, `Girl_btn`, `GirlTalk`,  `BacktoOutside_btn` to `energyNumber`, `girlBtn`, `girlTalk`, `backToOutsideBtn` respectively. Also a personal preference of mine is to try and use full words instead of abbrieviations, for example `girlButton`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `createGirlText.parent.removeChild(createGirlText);`

It's also worth testing if the parent exists before removing it.

Comment: I think it's a coding error on my part. I'm asking the createGirlText variable, which should add a class, to check if it's true. can I ask if something is true to only a variable that is a boolean?